# What is a trivial linear operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, invariant-theory

The question asks to find a non-trivial linear operator T to make a subspace T-invariant. I'm thinking of $T(x)=2x$, since $2x$ clearly stays in the subspace by scalar multiplication closure, but not sure if this is a "trivial" solution...

Comment: The identity is trivial, since it trivially leaves any subspace invariant.

Comment: So my example is fine then?

Comment: In the various math disciples, the thing that is called trivial is usually the thing that does not do anything, or is not significant. These are usually the empty set or the identity relating to the disciple or context.

Comment: Can you write down more details about the question? In this context, I might also consider any scalar multiple of the identity trivial, since these also leave every subspace invariant.

Comment: The question defines F as a field and A, B subsets of $F^{n \times n}$. A is the subspace of symmetric matrices and B is the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices. It asks to find a non-trivial linear operator $T: F^{n \times n} \rightarrow F^{n \times n}$ such that both V and W are T-invariant.

Comment: $T(x)=2x$ seems fine, but I'm kind afraid that there is something lurking behind... (as it appears too easy...)

Comment: In this case, the example of $T(x) = 2x$ is not exactly relevant.

Comment: why is that? It seems that it satisfies all the criteria

Comment: My bad, of course in the context of matrix multiplication it works fine.

Comment: @decas I assume you mean $V=A, W=B$?

Comment: Yes you are right. My bad

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks for a nontrivial linear operator  $T$ on the space of $n \times n$ such that the sets of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices are each $T$-invariant.

In this context, I'd consider $T = \lambda I$ to be a trivial solution, because it leaves *every* subspace invariant, so you're not even using the stuff about symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices.

The obvious solution here would be to take something like $A \mapsto A^\top$.  The symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices are clearly invariant, but most subspaces aren't.